# Yank column number in Vim

Tags: vim

I'd like to be able to easily make pretty *code titles* in vim, by making a macro. I'd like them to like something like this:

```
################################################################################
### Preamble                                                                 ###
################################################################################
```

To make these I'd like to start with a line with just:

```
Preamble
```

Then the macro will make the surrounding hashes and spaces. To do this, I need to somehow yank the number for characters in the title. So in the case of *preamble*; I'd like to copy 8, its length, to some register.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: It seems like you just want to use replace mode and paste in the middle after generating the box with hashes.

Comment: Are you dead set on a macro? How about a nice snippet plugin? e.g. [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) or [SnipMate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of counting the length, I would paste using Replace mode, as @FDinoff said.  First, yank the following line into a register, for example the `t` register: <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>

```
###                                                                          ###
```

Next, grab the `Preamble` line without the endline: <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>_</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>

Then, paste our line from `t` and move to the appropriate spot: <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>l</kbd>

Finally, paste `Preamble` using Replace mode:  <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+r</kbd><kbd>"</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend this style, as it's maintenance requires high(er) effort (and not everybody is using a powerful editor like Vim, or has your macros), but you can do this with the `strdisplaywidth()` function:

```
:echo strdisplaywidth(getline('.'))
```

Older Vim versions don't have this; `strlen()` is a replacement that will only handle normal ASCII letters.

Oh, and before you ask, you can create the header lines with `repeat('#', num)`

Comment: I agree completely with @Ingo Karkat here, please do not do this. Just don't worry about this. There are plenty other things to worry about, e.g. your code and quality of documentation.